# Money type for dad's partial distribution from 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k

My dad is 66, retired,  and has around $75k in his  401k with ADP. He wants to pull $5k out of his account.  ADP sent a form to fill out and I am helping him since he has some questions. On the form there are two sections A and B:

[image]

I assume that I should I skip section A and go right to section B. I can click the first check box for a “partial distribution” and enter the distribution amount of $5k. I assume under “payment options” in section B that I should select the first box that says “pay me 100% of the Partial Distribution amount in a cash distribution“. Is this correct? I assume that 100% means  100% of the $5k that  I entered.

I'm confused about the last section which asks about “money type election”.  It gives me two choices: ”pre tax rollover” and ”after tax rollover”. I don't understand which one to pick or even if I have to select one at all (it says select money type below if desired when I check the box). Can anyone shed some light on what I need to select?

All I want to do is get $5k out of his 401k.  I do not want to fill out this form incorrectly, delaying the withdrawal.  Do I need to check a money type or just leave this empty? Has anyone ever filled something like this out? I assume he would get a check in the mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would choose the "cash distribution" (I am assuming he's wanting the cash and not rolling it to a different retirement account). The other options are to roll over the entire amount you entered, or to do a combination (roll some over, take some in cash)

The last two check boxes determine how much of that $5K will be considered income (and possible taxable). 401(k)s are almost always funded with "pre-tax" money and is taxable when it is withdrawn. They *can* be funded with "after-tax" funds, which means that the contribution is taxable at that time rather than deferred, and you do not pay tax on the growth either.

It is rare to have "after-tax" funds in a 401(k) (his quarterly statement would show if there are), so most likely all of it is "pre-tax" and you can either leave them blank or check the "pre-tax" box.  **Note that withdrawal of pre-tax funds will be added to his income when he files taxes** and might increase your tax due. It might be worth talking to an accountant to see if you need to pay estimated taxes and avoid underpayment.

If he *does* have after-tax funds in the 401(k), then checking the "after-tax" box would save some money when he files taxes.

> I assume he would get a check in the mail?

Do they have some sort of ACH option where he can enter a routing number and account number for direct deposit? That would be faster than a paper check. Otherwise, yes he would probably get a check in the mail.

Comment: His 401k is almost certainly not taxed when he had it it was pre tax dollars. Everything you said makes sense so do I just leave the money type unchecked??

Comment: @JonH If it's all pre-tax then it won't matter. If you leave it blank it will be proportional, meaning if 90% of the total balance is pre-tax and 10% is after-tax, they would count 90% of the withdrawal as pre-tax. So you could check pre-tax to be safe but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you kindly people like you are just great